# How to add a smooth shake/wiggle effect to videos using FFMPEG

Tags: bash, ffmpeg

I'm currently working on a project and was wondering if there's any simple way to add a smooth camera shake / wiggle effect to videos in FFMPEG, I will be applying this effect to a transparent MOV file with text to make it slightly shake throughout the video to make it looks nicer.

(For reference I kinda want the shake/wiggle somewhat similar to this on the text https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7SSqXArVGXk)